# lost var in php

Tags: php, yii

I am fairly new to PHP and Yii, and the problem that I am not nor as the question in google, so the only thing I can think of is to ask the question to this list that I have solved many problems.

**The issue is as follows**: in the code that I attached, I read several records that I keep in array and after the process.

Well, if you look at the debug entries in foreach in he first, all goes well and the variable `$items` is loaded, but when I get to the second debug `$items` variable has the correct number of elements, but the elements are empty : `count ($items) = 2` but `$items[0]` and `$items[1]` are `null`

```
$idiomas=CListaMidiomas::model()->findAll();
$items=array();
$nombre=array();
$a=0;
foreach ($idiomas as $idioma){
    $nombre[$a]=$idioma->sIdioma;
$items[$a]=TblCategoriastexto::model()->findAll(
        array('condition'=>'id='.$data->id.' AND idIdioma='.$idioma->id_idioma));
echo "<br>---AAAAAAAAAAA--".$a."-----------<br>";
CVarDumper::dump($items); //in this moment is correct
if (empty($items[$a]) ||$items[$a]==null ){ // not enter because $items have content
    $items[$a]=new TblCategoriastexto();
    $items[$a]->idIdioma=$idioma->id_idioma;
}
$a++;
}
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>".count($items) ; //<<<<<<<<<<present 2
CVarDumper::dump($items);              // but in this moment t0 2 are null

for ($a=0;$a<count($items) ;$a++){
echo "<b>".CHtml::encode($nombre[$a]).":</b>";
$out="";
$item=$items[$a];
echo "<br>-----".$a."-----------<br>";
CVarDumper::dump($items[$a]);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<null
for ($b=1;$b<=20;$b++){
    $campo="tc".$b;
    $out.=$items[$a]->$campo . ",";<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<error
}
echo CHtml::encode($out);
echo"<br>";
}
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($items)` and see exactly what's in there. maybe it's not using indexes 0 and 1 for the sub-entries.

Comment: What does the `dump` method do? Does it only `var_dump()` or does it do something else? Like reset the variables?

Comment: What error are you getting? My guess is that `tc1` through `tc20` aren't all properties of all `$items[]`.

Comment: Can you show us the output?  I'm curious what is shown with the second call to [dump()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CVarDumper#dump-detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `if (empty($items[$a]) ||$items[$a]=null ){` will always assign `$items[$a]` to `null`.

To compare values, use the comparison (for equality) operator, `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: Thanks @kekkis, it's true. I've already corrected, but ... There must be some other problem, because in the line $out. = $ items [$ a] -> $ field. "," Keeps coming
$ items [0] = null and $ items [1] = null

Comment: Do not know why, but if I use TblCategoriastexto :: model () -> find (rather than TblCategoriastexto :: model () -> findAll (it works, and as I just want a record ....Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
if(isset($items[$a]->$campo)) {
    $out.=$items[$a]->$campo . ",";
}
```

Comment: CVarDumper::dump($items);<<<< dump the array

Comment: the first CVarDumper::dump($items);

array ( 0 => array ( 0 => TblCategoriastexto#1 ( [CActiveRecord:_md] => CActiveRecordMetaData#2 ( [tableSchema] => CMysqlTableSchema#3 ( [schemaName] => null [name] => 'tbl_categoriastexto' [rawName] => 'tbl_categoriastexto' [primaryKey] => array ( 0 => 'id' 1 => 'idIdioma' ) [sequenceName] => '' [foreignKeys] => array ( 'idIdioma' => array ( 0 => 'c_lista_midiomas' 1 => 'id_idioma' ) 'i....

Comment: In the second:

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>2
array ( 0 => null 1 => null )Castellano:
-----0-----------
null
catalan:
-----1-----------
null

the problem is that the content of $items disappears

Comment: whit if(isset($items[$a]->$campo)) { ... I know the error will disappear, but the problem of the loss of the variable will continue

Comment: Excuse me, but I have not responsive .... not let me use the original format @Marc,